# iOS - Dynamic Type and Interface Builder

Tags: ios, interface-builder, accessibility, dynamic-type-feature

Trying to implement support for Dynamic Type and have an issue. I set the style I want to use on a label or something in Interface Builder. I register for the UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification, and in the handler, I set the label's font to ... what? How do I know what style to use? Shouldn't there be an accessor that lets me find that out? If not, I have to put it in 2 places, which means they'll get out of sync and I'll be annoyed. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think this will satisfy you, but set the font to `[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleTitle2` or whatever style you set in Interface Builder.

Ignore the setting in Interface Builder. It’s not even worth setting. Interface Builder is a (mostly) *static* representation of the initial state of your views, but this is *Dynamic* Type.

You could subclass `UILabel` to make it dynamic, and/or join us on the dark side of setting up views in code.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 10, there's no need to follow this rationale because the `adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory` property allows an [automatic scaling](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#text-size) of the font sizes according to the content type size selected in the settings.

All the text styles are well defined in the [Apple reference site](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/) and their [size variations](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/criteria-ios.html#colours) as well.